# Are the resistance values (R1 and R2) in this circuit reasonable?

Tags: arduino, sensor, current, analog

This simplified circuit is intended to sense two limit switches (which can never be closed simultaneously-- at least in theory). The voltmeter shown is a place-holder for a connection to an analog input pin of an Arduino. When both switches are open as shown in the diagram, the pin should sense 3V31. Closing SW1 gives 5V and closing SW2 gives 0V.

This works great in simulation, but I am wondering about the total current as shown by the GND probe… My vague newby intuition tells me that there must be some minimum amount of current in order to be sensed by the A/D converter in the Arduino, but I haven't been able to find (or recognize) a spec for this minimum anywhere. (In contrast, the specs for the maximum current that a pin can sink are widely discussed.)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I may be way off base, but I believe this is a case where you don't want to over-think the problem, KISS.

When SW2 is closed the input pin is tied to ground and you should read 0. This is just like the case where an unused pin is grounded rather than left floating.

When SW1 is closed the input is tied to 5V (either Vcc or Aref), and you should read the max value (that is all the binary bits will be 1)

For both of the above cases, you could remove the resistors from the above circuit as they have no affect on the level of the input pin (that is one or the other of the switches is closed).

The only remaining case to consider is when both switches are open. If you did not have any resistors then the input pin would be floating. When the input to the ADC is left floating one would expect to read out semi-random values from the port, certainly not an unchanging value of 0 or MAX (all bits on). While I don't recommend omitting the resistors, you should be able to make this work without them.

While not explicitly part of your question, the more interesting case is if you wanted to detect one of several switches being closed with a single analog input pin. For a reasonable number of pins, say 10, this can easily be done with a resistor ladder ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder ). You can also Google R2-R ladder.

For a  walk-through of how this is implemented see: http://embedded-lab.com/blog/?p=4040

As an aside, if you only wanted to sense a single switch closure one would most likely use a digital I/O pin rather than an analog one, if available. The most common reason for using an analog rather than a digital pin for detecting switch closures is when the number of digital pins available is less than the number of switches.

Answer (score 3):

A/D converters typically have a low input impedance, which will be parallel to your R2, so the theoretical 3.31V may give a different (lower) reading. For example, if the input impedance is 10k\$\Omega\$ the equivalent of R2 will become 5k\$\Omega\$, and the reading will be 2.5V.
If the exact value is important you can use a voltage follower on the R1/R2 node:

[image]

The values you're using for R1 and R2 should be fine.

Comment: I believe the Atmels have a 100MΩ input resistance - not sure about impedence though

Comment: @Majenko: It's not about the input impedance of the A/D.  Being a CMOS input that is very high as you say.  The issue is what impedance does the A/D require the signal to be.  That is often around 10 kOhm, and significantly less for high speed A/Ds.  Some A/D can be driven differently in firmware to allow for higher source impedance.  Whether the Atmel can, and whether that is made optional thru the arduino software, I don't know.

Comment: @stevenh: I meant to ask before… What software do you use to make the circuit diagrams you post here?

Comment: @Kaelin - I didn't draw it myself. I found it on Google Images.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why the two resistors aren't equal.  That would float the value in the middle of the range when neither switch is closed, and at one end or the other when one is closed.  That would leave the most margin for differentiating between any two states.

A/D inputs are usually specified to require a minimum source impedance to work at their full speed or accuracy.  You'll have to look at the arduino documentation to see what that is, or possibly in the microcontroller datasheet if there is nothing between the analog inputs and the micro.  Keep in mind you don't need anywhere near full accuracy.  How exactly the A/D degrades with higher than specified source impedance is something specific to the chip, and in your case possibly extra circuitry added by the arduino.

Note that in your setup, the impedance of the signal is basically 0 when either switch is closed.  It is the parallel combination of the two resistors when both switches are open.  If both resistors were 10 kΩ, then the impedance would be 5 kΩ.  The quiescient current is the supply voltage (apparently 5V in your case) divided by the sum of the two resistances.  This would be 5V / 20kΩ = 250µA if both resistors are 10 kΩ.

Chances are things will work well enough with 5 kΩ source impedance.  You could try it and see.  You might not get exactly 1/2 scale with both switches open, but likely plenty close enough to reliably distinguish either switch being closed.

Answer (score 3):

The values are reasonable but can be higher.

Each ADC IC has it's own spec for how high a resistance input it can tolerate. A link to the datasheet for the processor concerned would allow us to point out the relevant value to you but, in the absence of a specific value, this is typically in the 10k to 50k range and often 20-30 k.

Values of 22k or even 33k will probably work well there. The maximum value specified usually relates to keeping the error due to RC time constantto under 1 bit of ADC resolutiom. As you do not care too much about resolution here it's likely that even 100K resistors would be OK.

Murphy says that both switches will be closed simultaneously at some stage. He also says that this will happen when you really really don't want it to.

There are many alternative circuits that do not risk extracting magic smoke from the power supply and switch contacts. eg

(1) place a 1k (say) resistor on series with each switch. Especially with higher resistor values this will have negligible effect n what you want to do.

(2) Assuming switches can be connected as desired.

Say 22K V+ to point X
 Switch one from ground via 10 k to point X.
 switch two from ground via 33k to point X.

S1 S2 =  0 0    Vx = 5V   Both open
 S1 S2 = 1 0     Vx = 5 x 10/(10+22) ~~= 1.6V  S1 closed
 S1 S2 = 0 1      Vx ~= 3 V  S2 closed
 S1 S2 = 1 1     Vx~= 1.3V  both closed

Results only for better clarity

5V   none
 3V  S2
 1.6V  S1
 1.3V  S1 + S2

An even better spread will be obtained with a little thought.

has its' You

Answer (score 1):

Some processors have optional pull-ups and pull-downs on the input pins.  If your processor has both, you could omit the resistors you have shown, though it would be good to add resistors (probably 470 ohms or so) in series with the switches.  Turning on the processor's internal pull-up, waiting a moment (probably somewhere between a few microseconds and a millisecond or so), and checking the input state will reveal if SW1 is closed.  Turning on the internal pull-down, waiting, and checking the input state will reveal if SW2 is closed.

If the switches have series resistors, one could speed up reading by having the processor drive each pin high briefly after enabling the internal pull-ups, and low briefly after enabling the internal pull-downs.

If internal pull-downs are not available (but pull-ups are), and if you have a series resistor on at least SW2, you could have a permanent, weak, pull-down resistor.  To check whether SW1 is closed, turn on the pull-up, drive the pin high briefly, and read it.  To check whether SW2 is closed, turn off the pull-up, drive the pin low briefly, and read it.